# What sort of function is this in this picture?

Tags: functions

first timer here.
I wanted to know what kind of function this picture depicts.
Every element of FF maps to one/multiple elements of GG but not all elements of GG.
[image: Here's the picture of Sets FF and GG]

Is this a partial function from FF to GG??

Comment: Ask yourself: is it injective? is it surjective? `Is this a partial function` Why partial?

Answer (score 0):

First of all it is a function since all the elements of the domain $FF$ are mapped to some element in set $GG$.

If you observe,$A,B \in FF$ maps to the same element in $GG$ namely $W$ and hence it will be a many one function .

Also there is an element in set $GG$ which has no preimage in set $FF$ hence it is not an onto function.

Hence,the function is a many one function and not an onto function.

Answer (score 0):

1) f: FF $\rightarrow$  GG as defined is a function, I.e. every element of FF is mapped onto some element of GG.

2) f is not injective, I.e. not one to one, since 2 elements of FF, A,B, are mapped onto the same element W of GG.

3) f is not surjective, I.e. an onto function, since Z in GG  is left out, means, Z is not in the image f(FF); means, there is no element of FF that is mapped onto Z.

Recapping:

1) f is a function.

2) f is not injective.

3) f is not surjective.